# WordPress Multisite Domain Mapping plugin is not working

Tags: wordpress

I am using WordPress 2.8.5 and i have installed wordpress-mu-domain-mapping.0.5.4.2.zip Plugin into the site , it is installed successfully to my WordPress site after i have activate the Plugin it is showing the error is '**The domain mapping plugin only works if the site is installed in /. This is a limitation of how virtual servers work and is very difficult to work around.**' but this plugin is working fine in WordPress Latest.

Can anyone help me to solve this Problem.

Comment: probably http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ will be best place to discuss

Answer (score 3):

use this on wp-config.php

```
/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */
/* Multisite */
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'localhost/wordpress');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

i think it will work wordpress is my project folder you can add like this

```
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'localhost/project_name');
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

you will need at least wordpress 2.9.2, consider upgrading your wordpress version